# Get arguments used within onClick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract some data from a page. The data is within an `onclick` method visible on the page

```
<a onclick="showGoals(this, 158233, 5, true)" class="showGoals" title="Show goals" style="text-decoration:none">+</a>
```

How can I pull out `158233`, the second argument (this value will be different each time). I essentially want to get the value and put it into an array.

Comment: Where is your `showGoals` function definition?

Comment: It's the second parameter to the function. What's the mystery?

Comment: You mean from outside the function? Like this: $('.showGoals').attr('onclick').split(',')[1].trim() ?

Comment: thanks @AlexandruSeverin, using the `attr` method is what i was looking for

Comment: do you want to put down as an answer and i will accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse attributes of existing html elements using jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

Example:

```
$('.showGoals')
     .attr('onclick') //returns 'showGoals(this, 158233, 5, true)'
     .split(',')[1]   //returns ' 158233'
     .trim()          //returns '158233'
```

*With additional checks to avoid errors in case the `onclick` attribute doesn't have a value, calls a different function or doesn't provide parameters.*